# Image getting cutoff

Tags: html, css, image, z-index

I am trying to insert a picture on a page.  The picture has curved edges.  The left edges always show up and the right ones do sometimes.  When I push the image to far to the right the right edge just turns into a 90 degree edge.  It only does this in IE.  Does anyone know why this may be?  Here is the code if it is at all helpful.  I tried giving it a z-index:100; but this did not work unless I am doing it wrong...

```
#userproftemp {
  background-image: url(%Image(NCC_CONTAINER_FL_B_FOOTER_PNG));
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  margin-bottom:-27px;
  margin-right:-20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying a size for this element that matches the size of your image would probably help.

Comment: so if the image is 958px wide set the width:958px;?

Answer (score 0):

make sure that #userproftemp is always as wide as its background image so it doesn´t get cut off.